# can i use same JDBC connection, statement and resultset to execute two queries in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I am authenticating user like

```
public static boolean login(DataManager dataManager, String userName, String password) {    
    boolean authenticated = false;      
    Connection connection = dataManager.getConnection();        
    if (connection != null) {           
         try {                           
             Statement s = connection.createStatement();
             String sql = "query";                 
             try {                   
                 ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);                                     
                 try {                      
                     while (rs.next()) {                             
                        String group_code = rs.getString(1);
                        String orgaunit = rs.getString(2);

                        authenticated = true;                            
                     } //end of while()                      
                 } finally {                     
                     rs.close();                     
                 }                   
             } finally {
                 s.close();                  
             }

         } catch(SQLException e) {               
             //System.out.println("Could not login from dataabse:" + e.getMessage());                
         } finally {             
             dataManager.putConnection(connection);                          
         }                  
    } //end of if (connection != null)      
    return authenticated;       
} //end of login()
```

I am closing connection in `dataManager.putConnection(connection)`. I want to ask once user get login then i have to update the status of user and maintain log history. Can i use something like this

```
try {
    Statement s = connection.createStatement();
    String sql = "query";                 
    try {                    
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);                                  
        try {
            while (rs.next()) {                          
                String group_code = rs.getString(1);                                                
                authenticated = true;                            
            } //end of while()  

            if (autherntcated == true) {
                sql = "query2(update status)"; 
                rs = s.executeQuery(sql);

                while (rs.next()) {
                    //dos tuff
                }

                sql = "anotherQuery";
                rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    //do stuff
                }

            }

        } finally {                      
            rs.close();                      
        }                    
    } finally {
        s.close();                   
    }                
} catch(SQLException e) {
    //System.out.println("Could not login from dataabse:" + e.getMessage());
} finally {              
    dataManager.putConnection(connection);                           
}
```

Means using same connection, same statement and same resultset execute other queries or is it wrong approach ?

Thank you.

**Edit
--------------------------------------------------------------**

```
if (connection != null) {
    try {
        String sql = "query";
        PreparedStatement prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        try {
            ResultSet rs = prepStatement.executeQuery(sql);                 
            try {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String group_code = rs.getString(1);
                    authenticated = true;
                } //end of while()
            } finally {                      
                rs.close();                      
            }
        } finally {
            prepStatement.close();                   
        }

        /// Addition   
        if (authenticated == true) {
            updateUser(connection, userName);
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        //System.out.println("Could not login from dataabse:" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        dataManager.putConnection(connection);
    }
} //end of if (connection != null)
```

UPdate method:

```
private static void updateUser(Connection connection, String userName) {

    try {
        String sql = "UPDATE users SET status_code = 'A' WHERE login_id = '" + userName + "'";    
        PreparedStatement prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        try {
            int numberOfRowsUpdated = prepStatement.executeUpdate(sql);                 
        } finally {
            prepStatement.close();                   
        }

        maintainHistory(connection);

    } catch(SQLException e) {
    //System.out.println("Could not login from dataabse:" + e.getMessage());
    }

} //end of updateUser()
```

maintainHistory:

```
private static void maintainHistory(Connection connection) {

    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO auditlog_user_logins(user_code,logintime,prstid) VALUES ();";
        PreparedStatement prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);          
        try {            
          int numberOfRowsUpdated = prepStatement.executeUpdate(sql);                   

       } finally {

        prepStatement.close();                   

       }

     } catch(SQLException e) {

         //System.out.println("Could not login from dataabse:" + e.getMessage());

     }

} //end of maintainHistory()
```

Answer (score 5):

> can I use same JDBC connection, statement

Yes. You can reuse them prior to closing.

> and resultset

No. The question doesn't make sense. The result set is the result of executing a query or update. There is no question of re-using it. I imagine you need to close the preceding result set prior to executing the next query or update.

Comment: It looks OK but you aren't reusing any `Statement` or `PreparedStatement` there, not that you apparently need to.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reusing connection because establishing connection every single time you're trying to query your database maybe a performace overhead.

As for statements, I would suggest switching to PreparedStatement. They are not only cached but one good way to protect yourself from SQL injections. So build up your query before-hand, execute them and finally close them when you're done. Reusing PreparedStatement would mean that you're substituting the parameter values for the the same PreparedStatement and executing the same.

So for example, if you've a PreparedStatement like:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT [col_names] from [table_name] where [col_1_value] = ? and [col_2_value] = ?")
```

In this case, you can *reuse* the same *PreparedStatement* multiple times by just substituting new values for the parameters. Generally, for your case you'll have multiple PreparedStatements. Since these statements are cached, they wouldn't be a big hit on performance when you execute the same.

Here's a good tutorial to introduce you PreparedStatement in case you're in need of one: ["Using Prepared Statements"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

ResultSets - well I don't see how can you reuse it. Close it as and when you're done with them. As per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object
>   that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next
>   result from a sequence of multiple results.

*However, make sure to close your connection once you're done using it. Re-usability is a good thing, but resource mismanagement isn't*

Comment: You mean to say i can close Statement and ResultSet. I mean that once i close the Statement and ResultSet, then use update and another query in the same manner and then close the database connection `dataManager.putConnection(connection); `. Is it?

Comment: @Basit: Updated my answer to include more information. Ideally you would want to reuse your *connection* object. ResultSet does not make sense and like I specified, I would suggest moving from *Statement* to *PreparedStatement*

Comment: Like when i create Statement `Statement s = connection.createStatement();` then i have to close it. Do i also need to close the PreparedStatement in the same manner as i am doing with the Statement ? I am first creating Statement using connection, then get `ResultSet` by using `s.executeQuery(query)`, and then loop through the result set. How can i replace it with PreparedStatement ?

Comment: @Basit: Yes you've to close your *PreparedStatement* after you are done working with it. You can read more about how to use it in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: I edited my code. Can you please check it whether i did it in the right manner ?

Comment: @Basit: You're not correctly building up your PreparedStatement. The SQL should be parameterized with ? for expected values, as I have done in my example. Here's a tutorial that can help: ["Using Prepared Statements"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 1):

Answered different Test case with same question.

> Can I use same JDBC connection, Statement and ResultSet to execute two queries in JDBC

We can reuse a JDBC connection and, to some extent, a Statement object for executing multiple queries, it's essential to handle resources carefully to avoid unexpected behavior or resource leaks. Avoid reusing ResultSet objects for different queries, as this can lead to errors and data inconsistencies.

- Closing a `Connection` closes a `Statement`, when `Statement` closed implicitly closes `ResultSet` also.
- Closing a `Statement` closes a `ResultSet` but not Connection.
- Closing a `ReultSet` only closes itself, not `Statement`.
- By default, only one `ResultSet` per `Statement` can be open at the same time.

**Best Practice:**

- Connections are not thread safe, so sharing them across requests is not a good idea.
- Opening a DB connection is an expensive, should use a ConnectionPool for sharing connections.
- Close `ResultSet` as soon as you finish working with `ResultSet`.

Comment: I don't understand what your code is supposed to prove or exhibt here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [UpdatableResultSet](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-updatable-resultset-in-jdbc/179).