# Having a trouble with "database is locked" error

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I've been searching since 2 days ago to fix this error pop up when i tried to show database values on jComboBox(variable named "nama_supplier"). After the value appeared on that jComboBox, i want to catch the other columns in database where the "nama_supplier" data was chosen, the code is:

```
private void pilih_supplier(){
    java.sql.Connection koneksi = new DBKoneksi().konek();

    try {
                String sqlSupplier = "SELECT * FROM tabel_supplier ORDER BY nama_supplier asc";
                PreparedStatement stmt = koneksi.prepareStatement(sqlSupplier);
                ResultSet rqs=stmt.executeQuery();
                while (rqs.next()) {
                    String pat = rqs.getString("nama_supplier");
                    nama_supplier.addItem(pat);
                    }
                    String select_supplier = (String) nama_supplier.getSelectedItem();

                   String sqlSelectSupplier = "SELECT * FROM tabel_supplier where nama_supplier = '"+select_supplier+"'";
                   PreparedStatement stmt1 = koneksi.prepareStatement(sqlSupplier);
                   ResultSet res=stmt1.executeQuery();
                   while (res.next()) {
                    String add1 = res.getString("kode_barang");
                    kode_barang.setText(add1);
                    String add2 = res.getString("nama_barang");
                    nama_barang.setText(add2);
                    String add3 = res.getString("harga");
                    harga.setText(add3);
                    }
                //rqs.close();
                //res.close();       
                //stmt1.close();
                //koneksi.close();
        }   

        catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}

rqs.close();
res.close();        
stmt1.close();
koneksi.close();   //these 4 codes should remove the error, but it doesn't work
```

Also, i've tried to use that 4 codes in finally{} method after try{} but it didn't worked either

Any suggest will accepted

Comment: Execute second statement only after closing the connection of first statement

Comment: yes that will work, but that's the problem. I don't know how to separate both of connections. if i separated them in a different try{}, the second one get the error "cannot find the symbol"

Comment: You can infact use the same connection. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634266/can-i-use-same-jdbc-connection-statement-and-resultset-to-execute-two-queries-i where you get the record from 1st query, close the resultset/statement use the same connection to find another set of records

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution , still using 2 connection but i'm separating them in 2 classes, this is the fix code. All credits to this man http://rahmadfaisal.blogspot.co.id/2015/03/tutorial-menampilkan-isi-database.html

```
public void tampil()
{
    try {
    java.sql.Connection koneksi = new DBKoneksi().konek();
    Statement stt = koneksi.createStatement();
    String sql = "select nama_supplier, kode_barang, nama_barang, harga from tabel_supplier where nama_supplier='"+nama_select_supplier.getSelectedItem()+"'";  
    ResultSet res = stt.executeQuery(sql);

    while(res.next()){
        Object[] ob = new Object[3];
        ob[0]=  res.getString(2);
        ob[1]= res.getString(3);
        ob[2]= res.getString(4);

        kode_barang.setText((String) ob[0]);
        nama_barang.setText((String) ob[1]);
        harga.setText((String) ob[2]);
    }
    res.close(); stt.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }              
}

public void tampil_combo()
{
    try {
    java.sql.Connection koneksi = new DBKoneksi().konek();
    Statement stt = koneksi.createStatement();
    String sql = "select nama_supplier from tabel_supplier order by nama_supplier asc";      
    ResultSet res = stt.executeQuery(sql);                                

    while(res.next()){
        Object[] ob = new Object[3];
        ob[0] = res.getString(1);

        nama_select_supplier.addItem((String) ob[0]);                                      
    }
    res.close(); stt.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```